# Automatically restart a .py every 30 minutes

Tags: python, twitter, bots

Recently I set up a twitter retweet bot, but after few minutes it's going down.

I used [this python bot](https://github.com/rhiever/TwitterFollowBot) and I'm using "nohup python mrbot.py &" to keep it running in the background after closing the terminal. Even if I use it as "python mrbot.py", it stops working after around 30 minutes. So could someone please tell me how to automatically restart it every 30 minutes?

I'm a very beginner at this. *Remember I'm running it in background using "nohup". I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Are you running Unix based system or Windows?

Comment: Have you tried crontab?

Comment: I have the worst knowledge in coding because I'm a graphics designer. I tried googling a solution for this but I didn't manage to find a solution. No, I didn't try crontab

Answer (score 1):

Crontab would be the ideal way to do it. Please search for crontab and how to enable and schedule a crontab job. 
For your example a crontab entry would look like

```
30 * * * * /path/to/your/python/script.py
```

Since you are running ubuntu, you should have python in your path and have a shebang in the python script. A shebang is the first line in your python script with path to the python executable, it is in following format

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a specific path to save a cron? I just default path it showed me. https://s22.postimg.org/8fr2wc4q9/Capture_2_PNG.png

Answer (score 0):

You are on Ubuntu, so you can use `crontab` command. Open terminal and type:

```
crontab -e
```

This will prompt you with (probably) an empty document. Then write the following line:

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/python script.py
```

This will make sure your script runs every 30 minutes.

You can read more about `crontab` and what it does and how it works [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Comment: I really appropriate your help. :) I have a one more question;
root@ip******/home/TwitterFollowBot/mrbot.py this is where I have the py. So is this going to be the same? "*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/python script.py" Please let me know.

Comment: So, the script is in a different machine? You should then run `crontab` on that machine. Another solution would be to copy the script to your current machine and run `crontab` in it (this last solution is assuming you don't need to run the script at a particular machine).

Comment: This is what I got after typing crontab -e.
https://s16.postimg.org/oz1paz1jp/Capture.png

Comment: Script is on a VPS. because I need to run it 24/7

Comment: This means you haven't created a `crontab` file yet. Just type 2 (edit on nano). And you will be prompt with the empty `crontab` file.

Comment: You should replace `script.py` with your actual script file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a specific path to save a cron? I just default path it showed me. https://s22.postimg.org/8fr2wc4q9/Capture_2_PNG.png

Comment: You don't have to write the file, `crontab` will do it for you. When you end writing the line, press `Ctrl`+`X` to quit. You will be asked if you want to save the file. Press `Y` and the file will be saved.

Comment: I manged to create the cron but will it still work if I run .py first time using nohup?  " nohup python mrbot.py & "

Comment: You don't need to run the script using `nohup`. `crontab` will run it for you.

Comment: But when I close the terminal .py stops :(  what's the solution for this ?